# Disabling <ctrl>+<super>+<down> shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, compiz, shortcuts

I have recently disabled the Ubuntu shortcut for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd> using the Ubuntu Keyboard -> Shortcuts menu since I wanted to rebind the shortcut using the program, Autokey, to be a <kbd>Page Down</kbd>. However, even after disabling the shortcut I'm still getting strange behaviour for the binding.

The binding now does two things; it always performs <kbd>Page Down</kbd> as expected, but if the window has recently been moved then it restores it (the old binding for the key combination). Is there another place where this shortcuts could still be defined (I looked in `compizconfig` but I couldn't find anything)?

Comment: Open ccsm > Grid > Binding > Restore

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I don't know how I missed it. If you want to post it as an answer, then I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> is a Compiz shortcut,:

Open `ccsm` → Grid plugin (Window Management category) → Binding tab → Restore.